# SettingsActivity Title Front Color change

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I write on a Guild App for Android with Android Studio.

And here is my problem,
In my **MainActivity** is the **title color** and **menu opener** black:

[image: MainActivity]

And in my **SettingsActivity** is the template from Android Studio is the **title color** And **arrow** white:

[image: SettingsActivity]

Where can I edit what both have always the same colors?

**Edit 1**
@Sodiq
here is my Code:

here my **settings_toolbar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here my the code in My **SettingsActivity** page:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
  ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.action_bar_root); //id from appcompat

  if (rootView != null) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.app_bar_settings1, rootView, false);
    rootView.addView(view, 0);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int color_one = settings.getInt("color_one", 0);

    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color_one);
  }

  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
  if (actionBar != null) {
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

This is my **color.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#363636</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

My **style.xml**:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here.-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

and this in my **Manifest**:

```
<activity
    android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

**Edit 2**

By Change to a **Toolbar** from **Actionbar**

have help me this for easy way from ***Sodiq***
for a colored Statusbar

**Code from Sodiq**

Change **Manifest** entry from **SettingsActivity**

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

To

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

And Change **Style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Thanks **Sodiq** for your Help

Comment: you can make custom tool bar and set the color in the styles file

Comment: i have try add a toolbar and  he have say"this Activity has a actionbar"
i was realy new with actionbar and toolbar

Comment: follow this link for example https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar

Comment: @JesseLukas yes, you can see on the link, you must use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` on your appTheme (I share that link because you new with actionbar and toolbar & i think that article can help you to know more about toolbar)

Comment: In your AndroidManifest.xml, what is the value of `android:theme` for your MainActivity and SettingsActivity. If you don't have `android:theme` value for those <activity> tags, what is the value in the <application> tag? Also, in your styles.xml, can you post your <style></style> output for the name given in `android:theme`?

Comment: I have no a toolbar in my Settings page with but bow i have another problem 
1.) variant the toolbar is under the status bar 
2.) variant the statusbar have the same color with the background from settings page

please Help i have no idea more was i make wrong

Comment: Please help me i have now a toolbar in my Settings page but the statusbar is now white not the color from my color.xml

@Sodiq you have say make a toolbar and now is my app crap only white color in my statusbar 
help me or test bevore you say make a toolbar

Comment: @JesseLukas make sure that on yuor theme style have  `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">YOUR_COLOR</item>`. maybe you can share your code?

Comment: @Sodiq
I have Edit My Thread on Top
with my Code

Comment: @JesseLukas check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" on your activity and only use`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` on your application on manifest

And changes your theme style `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Comment: I tested it and now the actionbar is back

Answer (score 0):

This have help me now

i have my create new Style in **Style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Settings" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here.-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and edit in my **Manifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Settings"></activity>
```

Comment: Did you solve it? if still not check my update answer

Comment: @Sodiq 
 
I had an update too late Sorry. Yours is clearly simpler than my variant, thank you for the help :-)  Read Edit Main Tread on Top