# Change Toolbar Textview Title

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I have Switch from 
[Actionbar to Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244754/settingsactivity-title-front-color-change/)!

For better Design i have change the font of my Toolbar 
with a Textview and this code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/NewFont.ttf");
toolbarTitle.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Now is on all Settings fragment pages the Same Text Settings

I have test ist with this

```
private void setTitleText(String Title) {

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/NewFont.ttf");
    toolbarTitle.setText(Title);
    toolbarTitle.setTypeface(myTypeface);
}
```

And here one of the Fragment Segment

```
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    //with this i call the title change
        setTitleText(R.string.pref_header_general);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and this not working i have this Error Message

```
Non-static method 'setTitleText(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

**Edit**

I have found a Easy Way

I have change this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/NewFont.ttf");
toolbarTitle.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

to

```
    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/NewFont.ttf");
    toolbarTitle.setText(toolbar.getTitle());
    toolbarTitle.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

And now works all Fine

Answer (score -1):

You can not call non-`static` method inside `static` method/class. You need to remove '`static`' from your `Fragment`:

```
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
```

Comment: This Working not Please Test is self 

This is my error Message when i remove static
This fragment inner class should be static (com.test.beta.SettingsActivity.GeneralPreferenceFragment)

Comment: Why did you call setTitleText method in the fragment? I suggest you to call it in your MainActivity

Comment: I call it up because he should know what fragment was called. You can times in android studio you look at the settings template. And since I use a textview he unfortunately does not change the title itself on the toolbar

Comment: Fragments have to be static so Android can recreate them on configuration change and app restarts. ||| On top of that if you rotate your phone this *inner class* fragment would still hold reference to its former activity and its `setTitleText` method. Calling the method would visually do nothing since the old activity is now invalid and presents a memory leak. Stop spreading malpractice, thank you.